# Why is the past tense used in this scenario?

Tags: tenses

Forms for user login [typically](https://twitter.com/login) [contain](http://www.memrise.com/login/) links like these:

> Forgot password?
>
> I forgot my password

Why is the past tense used? I would expect present perfect. I mean:

> I have forgotten my password

Comment: Saves space....

Comment: *forgot* is a lot shorter than *have forgotten*.

Comment: ‘I forgot my password’ could be an instance of the apparent American English preference for the past tense over the present perfect construction in such contexts.

Comment: To throw another reason into the mix. This is the Internet, where points have to be brought across fast. No need to use five words where two will do. Your users have better things to do with their lives than wading through an "Alas, it would appear that kind sir, or madam, has forgotten their credentials" every time they need to recover a password, which is typically precisely when they are also in the most extreme of hurries.

Comment: Yes, there is a need to save space and words. That's for sure. Yet, in my opinion these efforts should not change meaning of sentences as in this case.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Your comment is supported by the fact that amazon.com says 'forgot password?', but amazon.co.uk says 'forgotten your password?'. It also bears out a fundamental point I have previously made, namely that in Britain people are less inclined to abuse the language in the name of convenience. And that has to do with the fact that the language is called 'English' which also (by coincidence?) happens to be the name of the country.

Comment: "Got milk?"  Don

Comment: The use of the past tense instead of the present perfect construction in American English is not abuse. In fact, I’m not at all sure that ‘abuse’ has any meaning in a linguistic context.
The name of the country of which I am a citizen is the United Kingdom.

Comment: @Barrie England Where ninety per cent of the population (55 of the 61 million) live in one of the four constituent nations, namely England!

Comment: @Barrie England If a Geordie says 'I'm asking you for to go to the shop for me', people would rightly regard that as a regional accent, valuable, charming and worthy of respect. But no sensible Geordie would dream of writing it like that in a GCSE English exam. In standard English it is incorrect. Yet apparently if an American says 'forgot' when the context requires 'have forgotten', it is to be regarded as an authentic version of standard English. Why? Presumably because there are more Americans than there are Geordies. Is that a valid reason to accept this abuse of the Mother Tongue.

Comment: Geordie is a dialect, and not just an accent. So too are British Standard English and American Standard English. Each has its idiosyncrasies. In certain contexts, ‘I forgot’ is grammatical in the latter where ‘I have forgotten’ is grammatical in the former. That isn’t abuse, and talk of the Mother Tongue is meaningless.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I deduce from what you have said that Geordie 'dialect' is thus equivalent in status to what you call 'American Standard English', and 'British Standard English'. That opens up a Pandora's box, I would suggest!

Comment: @BarrieEngland Another point about 'forgot' is that 'I forgot my password' may be slick and convenient, but it is inappropriate to the context. So you forgot your password - but you may have remembered it again. 'I have forgotten my password' gives an accurate and up-to-date account of the position. It simply has to be the correct grammatical form for the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

*The Microsoft Manual of Style* (4th edition) recommends concise structure.  "Don't use two or three words when one will do."  page 7.  Also *The Global English Style Guide* recommends simplification of tenses for ease in translation.

Answer (score 0):

Application user interfaces are not conversations, contracts, speeches or debates. They are highly specialized and subject to their own constraints.  Expecting them to adhere to other standards is as silly as expecting a surgeon in the middle of an operation to have a formal debate about what the next step should be when something goes wrong. It’s not a pidgin or bad English.  It’s not necessarily about being shorter (reset password is shorter), it simply has its own standards that are used to suit its own needs and conventions.

It’s different, accept that.